# Computing a limit $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(\sin(\frac{1}{k})) $

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right) $$

I found the limit by approximating it from its graph. I could not get a proper solution
I drew the graph in desmos from which anyone can approximate the limit.
I also tried taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ to its first 3 terms as higer powers will be negligible which gives

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin ^2{\frac{1}{k}}}{2!} + \frac{\sin ^4{\frac{1}{k}}}{4!}\right)$$

In which I think the summation goes to zero since $\sin ^2{x}$ is a bounded function

Comment: Is k any number?

Comment: sry about that i had a lot of errors in the question which is asked i have fixed them now

Comment: What is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$?

Comment: $\cos(\sin(1/k)) = \cos(1/k+O(1/k^3))=1 + O(1/k^2)$

Comment: If you're seeking assistance with your question, it would greatly benefit potential respondents if you could provide additional context or share your attempted approach to solving the problem. This not only helps others understand your thought process but also encourages more targeted and helpful responses. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy's Limit Theorems gives that if $a_{n}$ is a sequence s.t. $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=a$ , then the Arithmetic mean, i.e. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{1}+...+a_{n}}{n}\to a$.

Apply this and directly get that the limit is $1$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(\sin(\frac{1}{n}))=1$

Here's a proof of Cauchy's Limit Theorem:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and find $N_{0}$ such that $|a_{n}-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N_{0}$.

Now find $N_{1}$ such that $|\frac{(a_{1}-a)+...+(a_{N_{0}}-a)}{n}|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N_{1}$

Thus for all $n\geq \max(N_{0},N_{1})$ you have \begin{align}|\frac{a_{1}+...+a_{n}}{n}-a|&=|\frac{(a_{1}-a)+...+(a_{N_{0}}-a)}{n}+\frac{\sum_{k=N_{0}+1}^{n}a_{k}-a}{n}|\\
&\leq |\frac{(a_{1}-a)+...+(a_{N_{0}}-a)}{n}|+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N_{0}+1}^{n}|a_{k}-a|\\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N_{0}+1}^{n}\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{(n-N_{0}+1)}{n}\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon \end{align}

Which comples the proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{1}+...+a_{n}}{n}\to a$

Comment: This is really elegant. Thx for the ans

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$1\ge \cos\left(\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right) \ge 1-\frac{1}{2k^2}$$
for all real $k$, and hence
$$n\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right) \ge n - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k^2}>n-1+\frac{1}{2n}$$
so that
$$1\ge \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\sin{\frac{1}{k}}\right)\right)\ge 1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}$$
which proves that the limit exist and equal to $1$.

Comment: Can you explain how the first step $\cos(sin{\frac{1}{k}}) >= 1-\frac{1}{2k^2}$

Comment: $\cos(x)\geq 1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}$ And $\sin^{2}(\frac{1}{k})\leq \frac{1}{k^{2}}$ (i.e. due to $|\sin(x)|\leq x$) @04-jayeshkumargupta